# Why isn't my json response not returned after the new NewOrder Event has been broadcasted

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, pusher

My store controller function is supposed to create a new order, save the order into the database, then dispatch an event and finally return a json response to me. But its not, its only excuting one of the two.

This is how my store function looks like, what am i doing wrong.

```
public function store(OrderRequest $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validated();

        $order = new Order;

        $order->user_id = $validatedData['user_id'];
        $order->user_name = $validatedData['user_name'];
        $order->user_contact = $validatedData['user_contact'];
        $order->order_items = $validatedData['order_items'];
        $order->order_status = $validatedData['order_status'];
        $order->order_type = $validatedData['order_type'];
        $order->order_total = $validatedData['order_total'];
        $order->delivery_fee = $validatedData['delivery_fee'];
        $order->delivery_latitude = $validatedData['delivery_latitude'];
        $order->delivery_longitude = $validatedData['delivery_longitude'];
        $order->paymode = $validatedData['paymode'];

        // $order->save();
        
        if($order->save()){
            
            broadcast(new NewOrder($order))->toOthers();
            
            return response()->json(['order' => $order]);
            
        
            
        }
```

This is the code for my event

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\Order;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewOrder implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    
    public $order;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('new-order');
    }
    
    // public function broadcastWith()
    // {
    //     return [
    //         'id' => $this->order->id,
    //         'username' => $this->order->user_name,
    //         'status' => $this->order->order_status,
    //         ];
    // }
}
```

Comment: Seems like something is wrong with your broadcast call, check your error log.

Comment: the broadcast works well without the response and when i also comment out the broadcast, the response works well to

Comment: Since the response works well when commenting out the broadcast, the broadcast is the reason that the execution stops before the response return. I haven't looked at what that broadcast does, but either it sends it's own response and exits the execution, or something is wrong and it throws and exception.

Comment: okay, thanks let me first check it out